# Setting fees with paytomany [Electrum JSON-RPC]

Tags: json, bitcoin, wallet

The following works:

```
{
    "id":"myquery",
    "method":"paytomany",
    "params": {
        "outputs": [
            ["2MzQCnSo839GFcyXNYeYGQD5wTzgN5exB96", 0.001],
            ["2Mydq5weSRT44Ej3ZLNykSFBzvnV8R8godU", 0.001]
        ]
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to define fees for each transaction.

Some documentation I could find:

https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/merchant.html#jsonrpc-interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your transaction has 2 outputs, actually its just a single transaction with multiple outputs so you pay 1 fee.
the JSON-RPC command would look like this:

`'{"id":"curltext","method":"paytomany","params":{"outputs":[["2MzQCnSo839GFcyXNYeYGQD5wTzgN5exB96", 0.001], ["2Mydq5weSRT44Ej3ZLNykSFBzvnV8R8godU", 0.001]], "fee": 0.00005, "password":"1234"}}'`